# Crosstab (contingency table, or similar)

Tags: python, group-by, pivot-table

I have a dataset like this

| id | january | february | march | april |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | scheduled | done | null | done |
| 2 | scheduled | scheduled | done |  |
| 3 | ongoing | canceled | scheduled |  |

I desire to transform this dataset in a matrix like this in output, where each cell are the occurrences of the exact intersection (keeping Null Values).

| event | january | february | march | april |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| scheduled | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| done | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| ongoing | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| null | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 |

Comment: I don't quite understand... why there isn't `canceled` in the `event` column? Also, in `march` there's `null` but in the output you have `0`...

Comment: Given: `df = pd.read_html('https://stackoverflow.com/q/76368967/7758804')[0]` Then: `dfm = df.iloc[:, 1:].melt()` and `dfm.value_counts(dropna=False).unstack(level=0)`. `pd.crosstab(..., dropna=False)` still doesn't count the `NaN` / `null` values. See [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYZy0.png). You can drop whichever rows you want from there.

Comment: `dfm.value_counts(dropna=False).unstack(level=0).iloc[[3, 1, 2, 4], [2, 1, 3, 0]].fillna(0).astype(int)` - `null`, and `empty` / `NaN` are recognized as `NaN`.

Comment: More info following Andrej's comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341), as well as [mre] in general.

Comment: What have you tried, and what do you need help with exactly? There's this existing question that covers a bunch of relevant techniques, so you might find your answer there: [How can I pivot a dataframe?](/q/47152691/4518341)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want cannot be done with `pivot` because your dataset is not in the standard structure. According to your dataset provide, for each month column, you use `groupby` function to count for the number of occurrences.

**Sample data:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3],
                   'jan':['schedule', 'schedule', 'ongoing'],
                   'feb':['done', 'schedule', 'canceled'],
                   'mar':['null', 'done', 'schedule'],
                   'apr':['done', np.NaN, np.NaN]})
```

**Output:**

```
temdf = pd.DataFrame()

for i in ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr']:
    tem = df.groupby(f'{i}').size().reset_index().rename(columns={f'{i}':'event', 0:f'{i}'}).set_index('event')
    temdf = pd.concat([temdf, tem], axis=1)

temdf.reset_index(inplace=True)

temdf


      event  jan  feb  mar  apr
0   ongoing  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  schedule  2.0  1.0  1.0  NaN
2  canceled  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN
3      done  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0
4      null  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN
```